# Using GCM in peer to peer chatting

Tags: java, android

How to make peer to peer chatting using GCM?
I know we could use GCM in push notifications from server to devices But is it possible to use it to send messages from one device to another.
Thanks

Comment: No, you'll need to go through the server. Aside from that, GCM is not a good protocol for a chat-application. Messages aren't guaranteed to arrive in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, per the [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html), GCM only handles two things:

- Registering your application with the GCM service
- Allowing 3rd party servers to send messages to registered devices

Of course, you could connect directly to your 3rd party server, get a list of registered users, then send a request to your server to message that user via GCM, but that is **not** a peer-to-peer device to device connection.

Comment: "then send a request to your server to message that user via GCM"
you mean that i can send the message i want to deliver to the server and it can deal with that by using GCM to deliver it ?

Comment: @amal - if you write both the application and server, then they can send whatever messages you want to each other. My suggestion was to use a non-GCM method (such as an HTTP call) to get your message and its recipient to the server. Then have the server use GCM to send the message to the recipient via GCM.